# How to use only one move function for all shapes

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I have a problem with **move** function in my code.
I need it to be :

1. one function which can move all shapes or,
2. multiple functions with the same name.

So far I have **move** functions with diffrent names for [point, circle and polygon](https://gyazo.com/3109d672f4761319e14403ad72c2ad15).
I can't figure out how to make **move** function for picture.

If you guys can help me with that **move** function for picture and edit all the **move** function so they work like I described at beginning.

```
    ;
    ; POINT
    ;

    (defun make-point ()
      (list (list 0 0) :black))

    (defun x (point)
     (caar point))

    (defun y (point)
      (cadar point))

    (defun set-x (point new-x)
      (setf (caar point) new-x)
      point)

    (defun set-y (point new-y)
      (setf (cadar point) new-y)
      point)

    (defun move (point dx dy)
     (set-x point (+ (x point) dx))
     (set-y point (+ (y point) dy))
     point)

    ;
    ; CIRCLE
    ;

    (defun make-circle ()
      (list  (make-point) 1 :black))

    (defun center (circle)
      (car circle))

    (defun radius (circle)
      (cadr circle))

    (defun set-radius (circle new-rad)
      (if (> 0 new-rad)
          (format t "Polomer ma byt kladne cislo, zadali ste : ~s" new-rad)
        (setf (cadr circle) new-rad))
      circle)

    (defun movec (circle dx dy)
      (move (center circle) dx dy)
     circle)

    ;
    ; POLYGON
    ;

    (defun make-polygon ()
      (list nil :black))

    (defun items (shape)
     (car shape))

    (defun set-items (shape val)
      (setf (car shape) val)
      shape)

    (defun movep (polygon dx dy)
      (mapcar (lambda (b) (move b dx dy))  (items polygon))
      polygon)

    ;
    ; PICTURE
    ;

    (defun make-picture ()
      (list nil :black))

    ;(defun movepi (picture dx dy)) 

    ; items, set-items used for polygon and picture
```

Answer (score 6):

Your objects are just lists, you will have a hard time distinguishing among different kinds of shapes. You could add a keyword, a tag type, in front of your lists (e.g. `:point`, `:circle`, etc.) to better dispatch your move operations according to that tag, but then that would be reinventing the wheel, a.k.a. objects.

### Simple functions and lists

> one function which can move all shapes

You can do that, provided you can dispatch on the actual type of object you are working with. `move` should be able to know what kind of shape is being moved. Change your data-structures if you can to add the type of object as the CAR of your lists, and use a CASE to dispatch and then move each object as needed.

> or multiple functions with the same name.

This is not possible, at least in the same package.

### CLOS

```
(defpackage :pic (:use :cl))
(in-package :pic)
```

Multiple shapes have a color, so let's define a class that represent objects which have a color component:

```
(defclass has-color ()
  ((color :initarg :color :accessor color)))
```

If you are unfamiliar with [**CLOS**](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) (Common Lisp Object System), the above defines a class named `has-color`, with no superclass and a single slot, `color`. The accessor names *both* the reader and writer generic functions, such that you can do `(color object)` to retrieve an object, and `(setf (color object) color)` to set the color of an object to a color. The `:initarg` is used to define the keyword argument that is to be used in `make-instance`.

Here below, we define a `point`, which has a color and additional `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
(defclass point (has-color)
  ((x :initarg :x :accessor x)
   (y :initarg :y :accessor y)))
```

The same for a circle:

```
(defclass circle (has-color)
  ((center :initarg :center :accessor center)
   (radius :initarg :radius :accessor radius)))
```

And a polygon:

```
(defclass polygon (has-color)
  ((points :initarg :points :accessor points)))
```

Finally, a picture is a sequence of shapes:

```
(defclass picture ()
  ((shapes :initarg :shapes :accessor shapes)))
```

You can make a circle as follows:

```
(make-instance 'circle
               :center (make-instance 'point :x 10 :y 30)
               :color :black))
```

You could also define shorter constructor functions, if you wanted.

Now, you can use a generic function to `move` your objects. You first define it with [`DEFGENERIC`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defgen.htm), which declares the signature of the generic function, as well as additional options.

```
(defgeneric move (object dx dy)
  (:documentation "Move OBJECT by DX and DY"))
```

Now, you can add *methods* to that generic function, and your generic function will dispatch to them based on one or more specializers and/or qualifiers.

For example, you move a point as follows:

```
(defmethod move ((point point) dx dy)
  (incf (x point) dx)
  (incf (y point) dy))
```

You can see that we specialize `move` based on the class of the first parameter, here named `point`. The method is applied when the value bound to `point` is of class `point`. The call to `INCF` implicitly calls `(setf x)` and `(setf y)`, defined above.

Moving a circle means moving its center:

```
(defmethod move ((circle circle) dx dy)
  (move (center circle) dx dy))
```

You can specialize a generic function on any class, for example the standard [`SEQUENCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_seq.htm) class. It moves all the objects in the sequence with the same offsets:

```
(defmethod move ((sequence sequence) dx dy)
  (map () (lambda (object) (move object dx dy)) sequence))
```

This is useful for polygons:

```
(defmethod move ((polygon polygon) dx dy)
  (move (points polygon) dx dy))
```

And also for pictures:

```
(defmethod move ((picture picture) dx dy)
  (move (shapes picture) dx dy))
```

### Immutable version

You could also make `move` build new instances, but that requires to somehow make copies of existing objects. A simple approach consists in having a generic function which fills a target instance with a source instance:

```
(defgeneric fill-copy (source target)
  (:method-combination progn))
```

The method combination here means that all methods that satisfy `fill-copy` are run, instead of only the most specific one. The `progn` suggests that all methods are run in a `progn` block, one after the other. With the above definition, we can define a simple `copy-object` generic function:

```
(defgeneric copy-object (source)
  (:method (source)
    (let ((copy (allocate-instance (class-of source))))
      (fill-copy source copy)
      copy)))
```

The above defines a generic function named `copy-object`, as well as a default method for an object of type T (any object).
[`ALLOCATE-INSTANCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_alloca.htm) creates an instance but does not initialize it. The method uses `FILL-COPY` to copy slot values.

You can for example define how to copy the `color` slot of any object that has a color:

```
(defmethod fill-copy progn ((source has-color) (target has-color))
  (setf (color target) (color source)))
```

Notice that you have *multiple dispatch* here: both the source and target objects must be of class `has-color` for the method to be called. The `progn` method combination allows to distribute the job of `fill-copy` among different, decoupled, methods:

```
(defmethod fill-copy progn ((source point) (target point))
  (setf (x target) (x source))
  (setf (y target) (y source)))
```

If you give a point to `fill-copy`, two methods can be applied, based on the class hierarchy of `point`: the one defined for `has-color`, and the one specialized on the `point` class (for both arguments). The `progn` method combination ensures both are executed.

Since some slots can be unbound, it is possible that `fill-copy` fails. We can remedy to that by adding an error handler *around* `fill-copy`:

```
(defmethod fill-copy :around (source target)
  (ignore-errors (call-next-method)))
```

The `(call-next-method)` form calls the other methods (those defined by the `progn` qualifier), but we wrap it inside `ignore-errors`.
Here no color is defined, but the copy succeeds:

```
(copy-object (make-point :x 30 :y 20))
=> #<POINT {1008480D93}>
```

We can now keep our existing, mutating, `move` methods, and wrap them in a `:around` specialized method that first make a copy:

```
(defmethod move :around (object dx dy)
  ;; copy and mutate
  (let ((copy (copy-object object)))
    (prog1 copy
      (call-next-method copy dx dy))))
```

In order to see what happens, define a method for [`PRINT-OBJECT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pr_obj.htm):

```
(defmethod print-object ((point point) stream)
  (print-unreadable-object (point stream :identity t :type t)
    (format stream "x:~a y:~a" (x point) (y point))))
```

And now, moving a point creates a new point:

```
(let ((point (make-instance 'point :x 10 :y 20)))
  (list point (move point 10 20)))

=> (#<POINT x:10 y:20 {1003F7A4F3}> #<POINT x:20 y:40 {1003F7A573}>)
```

You would still need to change the method for the SEQUENCE type, which currently discards the return values of `move`, but apart from that there is little change to make to existing code.

*Note also that the above approach is mostly used as a way to describe the various uses of CLOS, and in practice you would probably choose one way or another to move points (mutable or not),  or you would have different functions instead of a single generic one (e.g. mut-move and move).*

Comment: I need to do this only with functions, it's for school

Comment: Well this is a solution with *generic* functions :)

Comment: Traditionally a class like `has-color` would have been called `color-mixin`.

Answer (score 2):

Rough sketch, tag shapes:

```
(defun p (x y) (list x y))
(defun make-shape (type points colour data)
  (list* type points colour data))
(defmacro defshape (name args &key verify-points verify-args)
  "define the function (make-NAME points ARGS...)
to make a shape of type :NAME. Optionally 
evaluate the form VERIFY-ARGS with the
lambda-list ARGS bound and call the
function VERIFY-POINTS with the points of 
the shape, ignoring its result."
  (let ((type (intern name (symbol-package :key)))
        (fun (intern (concatenate 'String "MAKE-" name) (symbol-package name)))
        (all (gensym "ARGS"))
        (colour (gensym "COLOUR"))
        (points (gensym "POINTS")))
    `(defun ,fun (,points ,colour &rest ,all)
       (destructuring-bind ,args ,all
         ,verify-args
         ,(if verify-points `(funcall ,verify-points ,points))
         (make-shape ,type ,points ,colour ,all))))

(defun singlep (list) (and list (null (cdr list))))
(defshape point () :verify-points #'singlep
(defshape circle (radius) :verify-args (assert (realp radius) radius)
          :verify-points #'singlep)
(defshape polygon ())
```

You can use this:

```
CL-USER> (make-circle (list (p 0 0)) :black 2)
(:CIRCLE ((0 0)) :BLACK)
CL-USER> (make-point (list (p 1 2)) :blue)
(:POINT ((1 2)) :BLUE)
CL-USER> (make-polygon (list (p 0 0) (p 0 1) (p 1 0)) :red)
(:POLYGON ((0 0) (0 1) (1 0)) :RED)
```

And you can write some functions:

```
(defun map-points (function shape)
  (destructuring-bind (type points colour &rest data)
        shape
    (make-shape type (mapcar function points) colour data)))
```

And apply them:

```
CL-USER> (map-points (lambda (p) (list (1+ (first p)) (second p))) '(:POLYGON ((0 0) (0 1) (1 0)) :RED))
(:POLYGON ((1 0) (1 1) (2 0)) :RED)
```

And solve your problem:

```
(defun move (dx dy shape)
  (map-points (lambda (p) (destructuring-bind (x y) p (list (+ x dx) (+ y dy)))) shape))
```

Another thing you might want is a big case based on the type (ie `CAR`) of the shape, of you dispatch based on mapping the type to something in a hash table, or putting something in its symbol plist.